# Entry Form not working

Tags: form, entry

I have a simple entry form on the frontend that will not save form data. After submit it returns to the form page with no errors, rather than going to the url I set in the redirect variable.

I have done this dozens of times on other sites - the section ID is correct, the user has permission to create an entry (even tried as SuperAdmin, same failure). I then tried using the sample form from the Craft docs page, still no luck. I even recreated everything verbatim on another Craft site and it works fine.

Server configuration seems fine and there are no other issues with the website.

I am pulling out what is left of my hair trying to figure out what is going on - any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure there are no field validation errors happening?  You can check by calling `getErrors()`.  If that's not the case, does that box have Suhosin or mod_security installed?

Comment: Thanks, Brad. Yes, Suhosin is installed (but not mod-security). Is that a bad thing? There are no field validation errors - took it all the way done to title field only just to be sure.

Comment: My guess is you're tripping a Suhosin rule on entry submission.  You can try disabling the extension to verify that theory.